# Why is the 'type'-command not accepted in Eshell?

Tags: eshell

As I understood from the documentation of Eshell, every time that a command will be executed, it will be executed internally in Eshell/Emacs. When it gives an error code, then the command will be passed to the real shell, and the output of that command will be passed to Eshell.

So I began to wonder why the command `type` is not working in Eshell? In the terminal emulator, `type sh` gives me:

```
sh is /bin/sh
```

But in Eshell, it gives me the following:

```
("sh"): command not found
```

If the command is not found, it would be passed anyway to the real shell, right? I fail to understand why this gets stucked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> When it gives an error code, then the command will be passed to the real shell

No, eshell *is* the "real shell".  If there no such internal command, then eshell will look for an external command of the same name (this is what all shells do).  `type` is not an external command, it's an internal command of some other shells (try running `type type` in your terminal emulator).

Comment: TIL type is not a external command, but an feature of the shell itself. Thanks for clarifying it!